# Compose list with section headers using group by query with paging

Tags: android-room, android-jetpack-compose

Given a table with many rows, I would like to query using paging if possible.  When paging I would also like to group the data based on a database column and use that column as the section header for each group.

Data Table:

```
Id, section, data1, data2
0, "One", 1, 2
1, "One", 2, 3
2, "Two", 40, 20
3, "Two", 11, 21
4, "Three", 110, 23
```

Room Query:

```
@Query("SELECT section, * FROM data GROUP BY section ORDER BY section ASC")
fun getData(): PagingSource<Int, DataGroup>

data class DataGroup(
   @ColumnInfo(name = "section") val section: String,
   @Embedded val data: Data
)
```

Then in compose:

```
@Composable
private fun Data(
  viewModel: DataViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
viewModel.lights,
  val lazyItems: LazyPagingItems<DataGroup> = viewModel.data.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

  LazyColumn() {
    items(lazyItems) { item: DataGroup ->
       // I can iterate each item by this is not grouped
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Thinking about this more, I don't think a SQL "group by" is what I am after.  Probably something more like:

```
@Query("SELECT section, * FROM data ORDER BY section ASC")
fun getData(): List<Data>
```

With:

```
val groupedData = dao.getData.groupBy { it.section }
```

However at that point I lose the advantage of paging.  Possible to achieve this grouped by section result with paging?

Comment: If you're using compose, I think it's better to implement paged lists yourself than to use paging3. paging3 has a lot of limitations, and trying to work around them is painful. Here's a [paged list](https://gist.github.com/FishHawk/6e4706646401bea20242bdfad5d86a9e) I implemented that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the paging library already has a utility to handle this.  In my case:

```
@Query("SELECT section, * FROM data ORDER BY section ASC")
fun getData(): PagingSource<Int, Data>
```

Then map the data, and use insertSeparators to determine where to place the section headers:

```
val data: Flow<PagingData<Data>> = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 20), null) {
   repository.getData()
}.flow
   .map { pagingData ->
      mapped.insertSeparators { data1: Data?, data2: Data? ->
         if (data1?.section != data2?.section) {
           Data(section = data2?.section, isHeader = true)
         } else null
      }
}
```